# antd disable field based on checkbox

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using dynamic form in ant design library
I create checkbox and What I want to do is disable this timepicker field based on
the checkbox is checked or not
how can I do this

```
const Demo = () => {
    const onFinish = (values) => {console.log(values)};
    return (
            <Form
            >
                
                {/* dynamically created card */}
                <Form.List name="except">
                    {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                            {fields.map((field) => (
                                <Space key={field.key}>
                                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                                        onClick={() =>remove(field.name)}/>

                                    <Form.Item
                                        {...field}
                                        valuePropName={[field.name,'checked']} className="mb-3"
                                    >
                                        <Checkbox>مغلق</Checkbox>
                                    </Form.Item>

                                    {/* ------------- from_hour -------------*/}
                                        <Form.Item
                                            {...field}
                                            name={[field.name,'from_hour']}
                                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey,'from_hour']}
                                        >
                                            <TimePicker
                                                use12Hours
                                                placeholder="اختر"
                                                format="hh:mm A"
                                            />
                                        </Form.Item>
                                </Space>
                            ))}
                    )}
                </Form.List>
                </Form>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need state. You can control the checked value of the checkbox and use that state to conditionally render another form item.

There is an example of this behavior in [the docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-rule).